# spaCy token matching hangs + memory issue

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I'm running into an issue with spaCy token matching. When I try to run it on documents it starts to hang.

> Note, when I try to split the docs into sentences then run `Matcher` on the sentences I get the same problem.

Here is my setup:

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)


pattern = [
            {"POS": "PROPN", "OP": "*"},
            {"DOBJ": "NSUBJ", "OP": "*"},
            {"LEMMA": {"IN": ["ask","order","require","command","mandate", "urge"]}, "POS": "VERB"},
            {"POS": "NOUN", "OP": "*"},
            {"POS": "PART", "OP": "*"},
            {"POS": "VERB", "OP": "*"},
            {"POS": "ADJ", "OP": "*"},
            {"LEMMA": {"IN": ["mask", "cover", "face"]}}
          ]

matcher.add("MaskFinder", None, pattern)
```

Then I have an array of newspaper articles called `texts`. When I process just one text with:

```
doc = nlp(texts[0])
matches = matcher(doc)
```

I have no problem. But when I try to process more than one at a time:

```
for t in texts:
    doc = nlp(t)
    matches = matcher(doc)
```

spaCy hangs after the 3rd or 4th article and my system memory usage begins to spike dramatically.

Any obvious ideas what might be going on?

Comment: I think there is a problem with your pattern that contains too many optional parts. If possible, if you only allow 1 or 0 occurrences of the optional patterns, replace `*` with `?`. Also, see [this issue](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/3618) on Github.

Comment: I think the problem is just the pattern and the memory required to store many potential partial matches. That memory leak (since fixed!) wouldn't be an issue after processing only 3-4 articles.